# Does anyone know anything about the Mad Mimi Mailer API?

Tags: php, curl, yaml

Good evening good people. I have run across an issue that I am trying to resolve. Here is the context:

In an email template (using the email service provider Mad Mimi) I have a placeholder {name}

In my implementation of calling their API to send a transactional email, I am posting data using a cURL request. This data includes my api key and username, so I can't give that part of the code but here is a link to the documentation that I am using to try to get this done. (https://madmimi.com/developer/mailer/methods)

Here is the sample from the link above:

```
promotion_name=Welcome to Acme Widgets
recipient=Dave Hoover <dave@example.com>
body=--- \nname: Some YAML data\n
```

My PHP Code is this: (there are 2 other variables before these)

```
$myvars .= '&recipient='.$email;
$myvars .= '&promotion_name=Welcome';
$myvars .= '&body= name: Some YAML data';

$ch = curl_init( $url );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $myvars);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
return (curl_exec( $ch ));
```

The result that I get from the send is:

Email Result:Your body parameter was unable to be parsed, due to: (): mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 1 column 9. Please ensure the body parameter is valid YAML: --- name: Some YAML data...

Can anyone help out?

Thanks!!

---

Edit: I changed my code to be like this:

```
$url = 'https://api.madmimi.com/mailer';
$myvars = [
    "username" => "xxxxxxxxxx",
    "api_key" => "xxxxxxxxxx",
    "recipient" => "xxxxx@gmail.com",
    "promotion_name" => "Welcome",
    "body" => "--- \n firstname:John\n"
];
error_log('Mailer API Variables: ' . $myvars);
//TODO: Put the email transaction ID into the database FUTURE PHASE

$ch = curl_init( $url );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $myvars);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

error_log (curl_exec( $ch ));
```

I tried the body variable two ways. One urlencoded, one not. Here are the responses from both tries.

[05-Dec-2020 10:20:55 America/Boise] Mailer API Variables: Array

[05-Dec-2020 10:20:56 America/Boise] Your email has {placeholders} in it, but you have not specified their replacements in the body parameter, which was: ---+%0A+firstname%3AJohn%0A

[05-Dec-2020 10:22:10 America/Boise] Mailer API Variables: Array

[05-Dec-2020 10:22:10 America/Boise] Your email has {placeholders} in it, but you have not specified their replacements in the body parameter, which was: ---
firstname:John

Comment: In the edit, you're missing a space after `firstname:`. Sadly, I cannot access your link because my Adblocker seems to eat it. You definitely don't need to urlencode when giving an array.

Comment: Flyx, adding that space fixed it!!! I want to give you credit for it. I am marking your answer as the answer, but it is a combo of your answer and the comment above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php), `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` takes either an urlencoded string or an array. Yours is neither, since the string you give contains spaces.

An array seems easier:

```php
$myvars = [
  "recipient" => $email,
  "promotion_name" => "Welcome",
  "body" => "--- \nname: Some YAML data\n"
];
```

By the way, you seem to not show your actual code. The error message you give says your YAML starts with `---` but it doesn't in your code. The error implies that you simply forgot to include the linebreak after `---` in your string.

Comment: Sorry, I have been testing and changing so many things. You are correct that my code and the response didn't match in my example. I have tested with and without the 3 dashes. I will try an array, that does seem like it might be easier, I have tried urlencoded and not encoded. I have been trying so manythings the past day.

Comment: I made some edits to the code to strip away all other stuff and get to just the basics of the email send process.

I tried with the array, it didn't change anything. When I took out the placeholder from the email, it gave me a sent code. As soon as I have the placeholder, it doesn't work. I have verified that the placeholder in the HTML email and in the raw text are both {firstname}.

Comment: Flyx's answer got me most of the way there, then I edited my code and his comment on my edited code got me the rest of the way there.

Thanks Flyx, you are awesome!!